# Java multiple HttpURLConnections via Iteration?

Tags: java, android, json, url, httpurlconnection

Evening all, I'm testing some json fetching code for my android project, and I was wondering if having multiple open httpurlconnections that are all running is safe?

The API I'm requesting data from has a simple endpoint that also has a json element pertaining to the next page of data. ie. ...api/songs/ is the first page; within that first page there is an element for a url string to another page of data: .../api/songs/?page=2 and so forth until its a null element.

Say I have this try-catch-finally function that makes a connection, catches errors, and closes it at the end. Within the try block, I recall the same function so long as there is a next element within the parsed json; each call opens a new URLConnection as its designed for a single request per connection, if I'm not mistaken.

Thus, by the time I reach the point where the next object element is null, I would have about 14 HttpURLConnections open and close one at a time as it returns to the original call. Is this safe? It does seem to work as I already written code without crashing.

```
try {
    //Open HTTLURLConnection with given uri argument
    //read and store the results within a StringBuffer
    //if StringBuffer(when parsed to a json element) has a next element,
    //call this try block again
catch(IO/JSON exceptions...) {}
finally{
//close URIConnection if not null
}
```

that above psuedo code should be no problem I believe.

Comment: There's no problem with opening up multiple URLConnections.  Just don't assume they'll finish in order.

Comment: If you've coded it the right way, everything should work, there's no problem with having multiple URLConnections, just assure you are closing them properly in any case, because in other case it could lead to memory/resource leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've coded it the right way, everything should work, there's no problem with having multiple URLConnections, just assure you are closing them properly in any case, because in other case it could lead to memory/resource leak

Comment: Well, since each connection should disconnect and end on a finally block, I believe this should be fine. I'll throw an edit within my original question as well as when printing out the results via log statements, it does seem to run in the order I expect. More or less, this may as well be the accepted answer for me. Thanks.